# How to implement facebook module with Joomla build on Bitnami image running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, joomla, bitnami, facebook-comments

I am trying to implement a facebook comment box in an article. There is a "Facebook Comments Plugin" which is supposed to replace "{fcomments}" anywhere in an article with a facebook comment box. I downloaded it from here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-comments/16412

Unfortunately, it is not working on my Joomla 2.5.6. It displays the facebook comments box and it lets you login however, when you post a comment, it doesn't do anything. I have tried different browsers, computers etc. After hours of troubleshooting, I think there is a problem with the Joomla build from Bitnami. It is either missing a package or has the incorrect version because I have another Joomla website with another host and the same plugin works flawlessly on my other site. So this leads me to think that there is something wrong with my environment.

I thought maybe some ports were closed so I opened all the ports in the firewall and it still failed. (I have closed all the unnecessary ports now) I really think there is something missing in the configuration of BitNami specific Joomla build because I found some other people online who have similar issues while implementing Facebook apps with Joomla/Bitnami image. Can you please help me troubleshoot further?

Here is a link to the page with the broken facebook plugin. Notice it renders, but doesn't post.

```
http://184.73.244.219/joomla/
```

THank You

Answer (score 0):

Your FB initializaing script does not have an **app id**,

```
FB.init({appId: '', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

Maybe that could be the issue.

Comment: I don't think it needs an appId because the joomla plugin says that you only need the appId in case you need to moderate the posts. Besides, I tried it without an appId on my other website and it worked.